# Inglés vs Británico

Tags: gentilicio

¿Da igual referirse a una persona de Reino Unido como inglés o británico?

Sé que Gran Bretaña es la mayor de las islas del archipiélago británico, e Inglaterra es una de las tres regiones de Gran Bretaña.

Pero me entra la duda, por ejemplo si le decimos chino a un japonés o viceversa, podría resultar en ofender a la persona aunque se sepa que son dos países distintos. En mi país, Cuba, es común decirle china o chino a todas las personas con características asiáticas.

**¿Cuál es el gentilicio correcto a usar para referirse a una persona de Reino Unido?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, porque *británico* se refiere a los que son de Gran Bretaña (Inglaterra, Gales, Escocia), e *inglés* se refiere exclusivamente a los que son de Inglaterra. Gran Bretaña es la isla donde están aquellos países.

Y Reino Unido comprende a Irlanda del Norte y Gran Bretaña. El gentilicio es *británico*.

Comment: Muy cierto, aunque hay que decir que normalmente la gente lo utiliza mal, usando *inglés* siempre en lugar de *británico*.

Comment: Yo misma lo utilicé mal hasta que se me ocurrió investigar ^_^
Entonces, el mismo término *inglés británico* está mal utilizado, porque hay muchos acentos diferentes, incluso dentro de las mismas ciudades, como Londres.

Comment: @EvaThyssen con respecto al inglés como idioma no está mal, es como se conoce académicamente para diferenciarlo del inglés americano.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque el Diccionario de la Real Academia acepta *británico* para referirse a los naturales del Reino Unido, también se podría acuñar el término *reinounidense*, por analogía con *estadounidense*.

Por otra parte, Arturo Pérez Reverte ha utilizado en varias ocasiones el término *perfidoalbionés* :)

Answer (score 1):

La Inglatierra es una parte de la Gran Britanica, que incluye tambien, Galles, y Escocia.

Y el  Reino Unido refiere a la gran Britanica y la Irlanda del norte.

Un inglés viene de la Inglatierra. Un británico viene de la gran Britanica or Irlanda del norte.

Un inglés es siempre un británico, pero muchos británicos no son ingleses.

Comment: entonces??? tu respuesta deja mas confundido :)

Comment: @EmilioGort: In English, "Britain" includes England, Wales, and Scotland. "British" includes these three groups plus northern Ireland. So all Englishmen are Britishers, but not all Britishers are English (some are Welsh, Scots or Irish).